# Need some help writing a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a customer table like this and I need help retrieving information from it.

```
Foodid  |custid  |DilDay           |foodnum    |foodbill  |rating
  4        1        2017-01-02        2           500        7
```

I want to get the id of loyal customers I have from the database. That is the number of food lovers that kept coming back after their first trial. In this case the following days/week/month after the first order.

below is my query

```
 select custid
 from table 
 where foodnum = 1 and  dilday = between '2017-01-02' and '2017-01-30'
```

The above query returns the custid that ordered their first meal within that month. 
I want to get the custid of the those that continued after that month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
select custid
from table 
where foodnum = 1 and dilday >= '2017-01-02'
group by custid
having min(dilday) <= '2017-01-30' and -- ordered in month
       max(dilday) > '2017-01-30'          -- ordered later
```

Comment: I'd think about `count(dilday)` instead of `sum`. would it be different?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Still not getting what is needed though.

Comment: @wyn . . . How does this not return what you want?  It seems to be specifically what you want.

Comment: firstly the datetime in '' doesn't run unless i do this extract(month from dilday) = 1.
I am also trying to count the number of customers that comes back after the first month. But when doing that I get a new column with a total count of each custid foodnum.

Comment: @wyn . . . There is no `in` in this query.  Second, your question is "I want to get the id of loyal customers I have from the database", which is what this query does.

Comment: I did this
firstly the datetime in '' doesn't run unless i do this extract(month from dilday) = 1.
I am also trying to count the number of customers that comes back after the first month. But when doing that I get a new column with a total count of each custid foodnum.

I did something like this
`select count(custtId)from  table
  where foodNum >=2 and extract(month from DilDay) between 2 and 12 and
   custId in ( select custid from table 
   where foodNum =1 and extract(month from DilDay) =1)
   #group by clientId`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foodnum` is a sequential counter that increments with every order and you count them as loyal if they ordered more than once (even in January), you could do something like this:

```
SELECT custid FROM table
    WHERE foodnum > 1 AND
    custid IN (
        SELECT custid FROM table
            WHERE foodnum = 1 AND
            dilday BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-01-30')
```

...where the subquery gathers up all the customers that ordered in January 2017 and the outer query finds the same customer ID with `foodnum` greater than 1.

Comment: I think this works. Not yet sure. Still trying to confirm manually.